# Google Sheets: I want to create a formula or function that will automatically recalculate given certain conditions

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have tried "If, and, or" combining with simple script, and I am really new at the Apps script in Google Sheets.

What I need is: if any condition is true, I want the formula/function to subtract the corresponding value only for that condition from a total.

Background: a client is expected to serve 2-3 hours a day M-F (it can vary). If M=3, T=2, W=1, TH = 3, Fri = 3, then weekly total hours (WorkHours) = 12.
But the client may not always be scheduled on any day and these nonscheduled days can vary by client location.  When this occurs, I need to reduce WorkHours by the number of hours for a nonscheduled day.

For Example:
When Cell C4 = Monday and Cell C6 = x are true, that equals a nonscheduled day on Monday then the formula would only subtract Monday hours from WorkHours total = 9. But there can be multiple days, M, W and F. This can vary.

I tried the first half of this formula:

```
=IF(OR(AND(C4="Monday",C6="x"),AND(D4="Tuesday",D6="x"),AND(E4="Wednesday",E6="x"),AND(F4="Thursday",F6="x"),AND(G4="Friday",G6="x"))
```

But I can’t get the “then” half of this if-statement to work in a formula.
I tried combining it with Apps Script and I can share that, but it’s nothing to be proud of.

Thank you so much

Marby

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a wild guess from your data, try a [SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496) or [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583)formula

```
=SUMIFS(A4:E4,A6:E6,"")
```

OR

```
=SUMIFS(A4:E4,A6:E6,"<>x")
```

OR

```
=SUMIF(A6:E6,"",A4:E4)
```

[image]

*(If still in need do share a test sheet or more info)*

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the solution to your problem is simpler than it looks, and there is no need to use scripts to make this calculation.

try to do the following way

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DayWeek | isValid | TimeWorked |
| 2 | M | X | 3 |
| 3 | T | X | 2 |
| 4 | W | X | 1 |
| 5 | TH |  | 3 |
| 6 | F | X | 3 |

FORMULA TO CALCULATE
=SUMIF(B2:B6;"X";C2:C6) // result 9 as example

if your spreadsheet is fed sequentially, or has multiple collaborators, I suggest you use the rows as columns.

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | 3 | T | 2 | W | 1 | TH | x | F | 3 | FORMULA |

FORMULA
=sum(sumif(B1;">0";B1);sumif(D1;">0";D1); sumif(F1;">0";F1); sumif(H1;">0";H1);sumif(J1;">0";J1))

if you are sure that you will not have other numbers in the columns, the formula can be reduced to

=sum(SUMIF(A1:J1;">0";A1:J1))

Answer (score 0):

Initially, none of your answers would have helped with the sheets as I had structured them. But your answers sparked a restructuring of my sheets. It made them simpler and more useful to my users.

I really appreciate all your help. It helped me improve my product. Now that my sheets have been adapted, the formula I used =SUMIFS(A4:E4,A6:E6,"<>x") - working beautifully.

I have to really thank you - you helped me improve my whole approach.

This is great, really really helpful

Marby